# Examine memory with gdb 64bit out of bounds

Tags: c, debugging, memory, gdb

Using

```
char *addr = getenv("CNFG")
```

I get

```
0x7fffffffebea
```

Then debugging my program I get this error message:

```
(gdb) x/ls 0x7fffffffebea 
0x7fffffffebea:  <Address 0x7fffffffebea out of bounds>
```

How do I to examine the contents of that environment variable (in order to to check that has a valid value)?

Comment: Did you copy/paste the address value, or did you type it in by hand? Does `p addr` return an error too?

Comment: Is this 32 bit? 64 bit? If that's the value of `addr` it looks like a 48 bit pointer, which seems a bit odd.

Comment: @david.pfx: That's a pretty normal display format for GDB running on a 64-bit platform; memory addresses are really only 48-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get `0x7fffffffebea`

It's not clear from your question, but you likely get that value when running program outside of GDB. That value should change from run to run (due to address space layout randomization), *and* you should get a different value inside GDB (due to differences in stack layout when running under GDB).

In other words, run the program under GDB, print addr, *then* use `x/s addr` to examine the string.

Comment: Thanks. I first disabled virtual address randomization to get always the same address. I must have been asleep... now I get a valid string: (gdb) x/1s 0x7fffffffebea 0x7fffffffebea:  "RM=xterm" (the offset to CNFG does not matter, as I can look for it)